# php unexpected ')' parse error

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use a function to return a default param in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050714/can-i-use-a-function-to-return-a-default-param-in-php)
>   [Using function result as a default argument in PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435108/using-function-result-as-a-default-argument-in-php-function)

I am trying to set default value for a function. I want the function `$expires` default value to be `time() + 604800`.

I am trying

```
public function set($name,$value,$expires = time()+604800) {
    echo $expires;
    return setcookie($name, $value, $expires);
    }
```

But I get an error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in /var/www/running/8ima/lib/cookies.lib.php on line 38

How should I write it?

Comment: Wouldn't `if (!$expires) { $expires = time() + 604800; }` do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$expires = time()+604800
```

in the function definition.

Default value can't be the result of a function, only a simple value
QUoting from [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function call.

Use:

```
public function set($name,$value,$expires = NULL) { 
    if (is_null($expires))
        $expires = time()+604800;
    echo $expires; 
    return setcookie($name, $value, $expires); 
}
```

Comment: +1 first answer that actually explains what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a function call in your params declaration.

Do it this way:

```
public function set($name,$value,$expires = null) {
    if(is_null($expires)) $expires = time()+604800;
    echo $expires;
    return setcookie($name, $value, $expires);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function set($name,$value,$expires = NULL) {
    if(is_null($expires)) {
        $expires = time() + 604800;
    }
    echo $expires;
    return setcookie($name, $value, $expires);
}
```

Comment: +1 if you can also explain why.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
public function set($name,$value,$expires = null) {
 if($expires === null){$expires = time()+604800);
 echo $expires;
 return setcookie($name, $value, $expires);
}
```